# Can't boot from cd

Tags: 10.04, boot

I have an i7 PC with 16gb RAM running Window 7.
I want to learn to use Linux booting from the CD before I install it on a HD.
I downloaded the 10.04 LTS (64-bit) iso file and ran the md5sum check. OK so far.
I burned it to cds twice, once with Windows, once with Nero. In both cases, the individual files and folders are visible in the directory. Does this verify it was burned correctly?

The following is the same for both cd copies...
If/when I install Linux, I'll change the BIOS, but for now I'm using F12 at start-up.
At first, I get a purple screen with a couple of symbols. No text. 
Then I get a black screen with a flashing cursor.
Then I get a second purple screen with the name Ubuntu and 5 dots changing between white and red. This lasts for about 45 seconds.
Then it goes black and I have to cut power to the tower to recover.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Press `Esc` while the Plymouth loader appears (i.e.  Ubuntu and 5 dots ). You can see the logs and see where it is stuck/ error is coming. Post it here.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
I tried your suggestion. I got a screen full of text that appeared for only a few seconds before I got the Black Screen of Death again. There was no time to read it all, much less write it down. I assume PrtScrn doesn't function during a boot attempt, right?
Any hints on what I'm looking for and where on the screen it might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare USB flash drive available you could try using that. Install Universal USB installer. (download from this link [HERE](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button))

Follow the instructions from the Ubuntu website found [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

Boot into USB. (Using F12?)

I find this method more reliable as burning to CD can sometimes fail with a faulty CD drive or media.

If this also does not work, you could attempt to install Ubuntu 11.10 or wait until April 26th and install Ubuntu 12.04 as an upgraded version might solve your problem.